# AWS golang SDK set debugging level

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to debug the S3 upload session in Go code which I am initiating like this

```
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Endpoint: aws.String(os.Getenv("AWS_LOCAL_S3_ENDPOINT")),
        Region:   aws.String(os.Getenv("AWS_REGION")),
        // LogLevel: aws.LogDebug,
    }))
```

Now what i have problem with is settithe LogLevel param. Can't figure this out. I am very much beginner in golang.

The idea is to debug the S3 upload process. it is complaining that bucket is not available, but it is. 
`AWS_LOCAL_S3_ENDPOINT` is the localstack endpoint for mocked S3

AWS Session Config doc link [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/#Config)

Comment: You say you have a problem setting the logLevel. What’s the problem? Can you share the compiler error if any? Have you checked the example in https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/aws/config_test.go#L19 ?

Comment: that did the trick. thanks a lot. i don't know how i've missed that